# How does the recursive GetEndpoints-Method of the OPC/UA-.NETStandard work?

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, opc-ua

I wanted to learn some C# and .net and network stuff. Thus, I've chosen the OPC UA code.

On github: UA-.NETStandard/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Stack/Client/DiscoveryClient.cs

But I really don't understand how this method works:

```
    public virtual EndpointDescriptionCollection GetEndpoints(StringCollection profileUris)
    {
        EndpointDescriptionCollection endpoints = null;

        GetEndpoints(
            null,
            this.Endpoint.EndpointUrl,
            null,
            profileUris,
            out endpoints);

        return PatchEndpointUrls(endpoints);
    }
```

I understand that it is a recursive method, calling itself over and over again.

1. How does it ever end? Is it maybe a continuous polling?
2. Is the inner call's argument(s) "null,this.Endpoint.EndpointUrl,null,profileUris,out endpoints" a StringCollection? Because the StringCollection "profileUris" is already a StringCollection!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method is not actually recursive. You're calling a different method(or "overload") altogether. You can check it out [in the code repo](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/blob/master/Stack/Opc.Ua.Core/Stack/Client/DiscoveryClient.cs#L155).

Note that the class is partial. If you follow the references from the repo, you'll see that it leads to the generated client and server partial classes.

[image: Github reference]